# Storing input from field as variable with swift 3

Tags: ios, swift

I realize this question has been asked numerous times before, but I can't quite get the solutions to work, even by just copying and pasting them, and suspect that most swift documentation spans the three versions since swift's release.

I'm attempting to do something as simple as storing a variable from a field input and not having much luck.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {


@IBOutlet var userNumber: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var userField: UITextField!

@IBAction func userButton(_ sender: UIButton) {

    let userInput = userField.text
    //some action 



}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

}

Comment: Did you connect IBOutlet and IBAction with the storyboard?

Answer (score 0):

You should check whether you have set your textfield's delegate with respect to parent view controller.

Go to storyboard. 
Select textfield. 
Right click on it.
set delegate from textfield to view controller